# Conormal sheaf of the twisted cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be the twisted cubic, i.e. cut out by the ideal $(wy-x^2,xz-y^2,wz-xy)$. What is a good way to find its conormal sheaf?

It's fairly hard to directly calculate $I/I^2$ as there are so many relations so I doubt that's the right way to proceed...

Comment: The twisted cubic is isomorphic to projective line, hence its cotangent sheaf is isomorphic to $\mathcal O(-2)$. Or maybe you mean the conormal sheaf?

Answer (score 2):

To compute the conormal sheaf one can use the standard exact seqeunce
$$
0 \to I/I^2 \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^3}\vert_C \to \Omega_C \to 0
$$
together with the two Euler sequences
$$
0 \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^3} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-1)^{\oplus 4} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3} \to 0
$$
and (since $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$)
$$
0 \to \Omega_C \to \mathcal{O}_C(-1)^{\oplus 2} \to \mathcal{O}_C \to 0.
$$
Their combination (with an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-1)\vert_C \cong \mathcal{O}_C(-3)$ taken into account) gives an exact sequence
$$
0 \to I/I^2 \to \mathcal{O}_C(-3)^{\oplus 4} \to \mathcal{O}_C(-1)^{\oplus 2} \to 0,
$$
where the second arrow is given by the jacobain matrix of the map 
$$
C \to \mathbb{P}^3,\qquad (u,v) \mapsto (u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3).
$$
The jacobain matrix is equal to
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}3u^2 & 2uv & v^2 & 0 \\ 0 & u^2 & 2uv & 3v^2 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
and using it it is easy to check that 
$$
I/I^2 \cong \mathcal{O}_C(-5)^{\oplus 2}.
$$

Comment: Why is $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-1)|_C \cong \mathscr{O}_C(-3)$? Shouldn't it be $\mathscr{O}_C(-1)$ by definition?

Comment: @AaronJohnson: Because the map $C \to \mathbb{P}^3$ is of degree~3.

Comment: Hi Sasha, I have had some issues understanding parts of your answer. I've posted a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604985/on-an-exact-sequence-related-to-the-conormal-bundle-of-a-rational-space-curve) if you have time. No worries if not.